# hotstring to turn Mr into Mr. and Mrs into Mrs

Tags: autohotkey

Microsoft Word red-flags my Mr and wants to change it to Mr. and Mrs. every time. Since I have gotten used to typing Mr and Mrs, I want to use Autohotkey to change it automatically as I type...

Right now, I have:

```
:c*:Mrs::Mrs. 
:c*:Mr::Mr.
```

But as you can probably guess, when I type `Mrs` it changes to `Mr.S` because of the Mr command, and the Mrs command is never called

Is it possible for me to get it to type `Mrs.` when I type `Mrs`, and `Mr.` when I type `Mr`?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the docs on [Hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) and comparing your code I see that you have * option which is triggering your hotstring immediately, this removes the need for a End Character (default is space, enter, tab) to trigger the hotstring replacement. To correct this behavior simply remove the *

```
:c:Mrs::Mrs. 
:c:Mr::Mr.
```

Answer (score 1):

Like ahkcoder, but I would have used an extra space and replaced the space with an asterisk.

```
:*:mr ::Mr. `
:*:mrs ::Mrs. `
```

By not using :c:, this makes it case independent.
Within Word, you could have used auto correct as well.

Comment: why? adding spaces is unnecessary. apart from the `c`, this does the exact same thing as ahkcoder's answer, but it looks worse. tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I am so used to defining my own ending characters that I always use the same method (with a space here, but normally my ending characters are: =, / and \), so you are right, this made no sense here.